# Rip a DVD title with IFO and BUP files from the command line

Tags: command-line, backup, dvd, dvd-backup

Like the title says, I would like to rip a DVD title with IFO and BUP files from the command line. I have tried several programs with varying results.

---

**Using dvdbackup:**

```
dvdbackup -i imagefile.img -o /home/username/tmp -t 1
```

...but this way there are no IFO or BUP files. So I continued to re-author result using dvdauthor:

```
dvdauthor -t -o /home/username/tmp/dvd *.VOB
```

...but the re-authored files do not include some important info, like the subtitle language names.

---

**Using vobcopy:**

```
vobcopy -n 1 -i imagefile.img -o /home/username/tmp
```

...No IFO or BUP files.

---

**Using mplayer:**

```
mplayer dvd://1 -dvd-device imagefile.img -title 1 -dumpstream -dumpfile title1.vob
```

...No IFO or BUP files.

---

**Using cpvts:**

```
cpvts -d /media/dvd -t 1 /home/username/tmp
```

cpvts has some problems. It rips the whole titleset, not the individual title. This takes a lot of space when ripping several titles separately. Also it needs some dependecies, which are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `dvdbackup -M` (-M for mirroring) I do get all the ifo and bup files. One thing to keep in mind is not to mount the device.

Comment: I explained a little why this is an answer